# How to rbind tibbles in a big list for each component of the list

Tags: r, list, dplyr, purrr, tibble

I have list of >2 components made of tibbles. Each tibble has 2 columns(cols), column 1 is a character vector and column 2 is a tibble of some summary statistics. i want to rbind/collapse tibbles of summary statistics per each componenent of the list to something like this

```
$h.chr6
  methyl_stats      
1 <tibble [259 × 12]>

$h.chr7
  methyl_stats       
1 <tibble [375 × 12]>
```

I have tried the following but still didn't work

```
library(tidyverse)
dataTibblesInList %>% map(~select(.x, methyl_stats)) %>% map(bind_rows)

dataTibblesInList %>% map(~select(.x, methyl_stats)) %>% map(~mutate(.x, bindedRows = map(methyl_stats, function(x){plyr::ldply(x, data.frame)})))
```

Data looks like this

```
> str(dataTibblesInList)
List of 2
 $ h.chr6: tibble [6 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ sample      : chr [1:6] "P_1" "P_2" "P_3" "P_4" ...
  ..$ methyl_stats:List of 6
  .. ..$ : tibble [49 × 12] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. .. ..$ chrom    : chr [1:49] "chr6" "chr6" "chr6" "chr6" ...
  .. .. ..$ pos      : num [1:49] 60470 60658 60798 60858 60910 ...
  .. .. ..$ strand   : chr [1:49] "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
  .. .. ..$ mean_stat: num [1:49] 0.998 0.961 0.973 0.999 0.997 ...
  .. .. ..$ med_stat : num [1:49] 0.998 0.961 0.973 0.999 0.997 ...
  .. .. ..$ prod_stat: num [1:49] 0.998 0.961 0.973 0.999 0.997 ...
  .. .. ..$ max_stat : num [1:49] 0.998 0.961 0.973 0.999 0.997 ...
  .. .. ..$ min_stat : num [1:49] 0.998 0.961 0.973 0.999 0.997 ...
  .. .. ..$ sd_stat  : num [1:49] NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. .. ..$ iqr_stat : num [1:49] 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..$ num_stat : int [1:49] 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 3 3 3 ...
  .. .. ..$ sample   : chr [1:49] "P_1" "P_1" "P_1" "P_1" ...
  .. ..$ : tibble [74 × 12] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. .. ..$ chrom    : chr [1:74] "chr6" "chr6" "chr6" "chr6" ...
  .. .. ..$ pos      : num [1:74] 70056 70806 70818 70846 70855 ...
  .. .. ..$ strand   : chr [1:74] "+" "+" "+" "+" ...
  .. .. ..$ mean_stat: num [1:74] 0.995681 0.000332 0.000129 0.997282 0.988107 ...
  .. .. ..$ med_stat : num [1:74] 0.995681 0.000332 0.000129 0.997282 0.988107 ...
  .. .. ..$ prod_stat: num [1:74] 0.995681 0.000332 0.000129 0.997282 0.988107 ...
  .. .. ..$ max_stat : num [1:74] 0.995681 0.000332 0.000129 0.997282 0.988107 ...
  .. .. ..$ min_stat : num [1:74] 0.995681 0.000332 0.000129 0.997282 0.988107 ...
  .. .. ..$ sd_stat  : num [1:74] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. .. ..$ iqr_stat : num [1:74] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..$ num_stat : int [1:74] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. ..$ sample   : chr [1:74] "P_2" "P_2" "P_2" "P_2" ...
  .. ..$ : tibble [23 × 12] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. .. ..$ chrom    : chr [1:23] "chr6" "chr6" "chr6" "chr6" ...
  .. .. ..$ pos      : num [1:23] 60469 60657 60797 60857 60909 ...
  .. .. ..$ strand   : chr [1:23] "+" "+" "+" "+" ...
  .. .. ..$ mean_stat: num [1:23] 0.000452 0.998846 0.000215 0.997526 0.991608 ...
  .. .. ..$ med_stat : num [1:23] 0.000452 0.998846 0.000215 0.997526 0.991608 ...
  .. .. ..$ prod_stat: num [1:23] 0.000452 0.998846 0.000215 0.997526 0.991608 ...
  .. .. ..$ max_stat : num [1:23] 0.000452 0.998846 0.000215 0.997526 0.991608 ...
  .. .. ..$ min_stat : num [1:23] 0.000452 0.998846 0.000215 0.997526 0.991608 ...
  .. .. ..$ sd_stat  : num [1:23] NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. .. ..$ iqr_stat : num [1:23] 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..$ num_stat : int [1:23] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 4 4 4 ...
  .. .. ..$ sample   : chr [1:23] "P_3" "P_3" "P_3" "P_3" ...
  .. ..$ : tibble [26 × 12] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. .. ..$ chrom    : chr [1:26] "chr6" "chr6" "chr6" "chr6" ...
  .. .. ..$ pos      : num [1:26] 60469 60470 60657 60658 60797 ...
  .. .. ..$ strand   : chr [1:26] "+" "-" "+" "-" ...
  .. .. ..$ mean_stat: num [1:26] 0.00098 0.72577 0.80719 0.50109 0.45971 ...
  .. .. ..$ med_stat : num [1:26] 0.00098 0.95259 0.80719 0.5034 0.45971 ...
  .. .. ..$ prod_stat: num [1:26] 9.80e-04 2.18e-04 8.07e-01 2.76e-06 3.64e-04 ...
  .. .. ..$ max_stat : num [1:26] 0.00098 0.99766 0.80719 0.99732 0.91902 ...
  .. .. ..$ min_stat : num [1:26] 0.00098 0.000241 0.807191 0.00023 0.000397 ...
  .. .. ..$ sd_stat  : num [1:26] NA 0.485 NA 0.572 0.65 ...
  .. .. ..$ iqr_stat : num [1:26] 0 0.311 0 0.986 0.459 ...
  .. .. ..$ num_stat : int [1:26] 1 4 1 4 2 4 2 4 2 4 ...
  .. .. ..$ sample   : chr [1:26] "P_4" "P_4" "P_4" "P_4" ...
  .. ..$ : tibble [36 × 12] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. .. ..$ chrom    : chr [1:36] "chr6" "chr6" "chr6" "chr6" ...
  .. .. ..$ pos      : num [1:36] 60469 60657 60797 60857 60858 ...
  .. .. ..$ strand   : chr [1:36] "+" "+" "+" "+" ...
  .. .. ..$ mean_stat: num [1:36] 0.986 0.271 0.999 0.992 0.997 ...
  .. .. ..$ med_stat : num [1:36] 0.986 0.271 0.999 0.992 0.997 ...
  .. .. ..$ prod_stat: num [1:36] 0.986 0.271 0.999 0.992 0.997 ...
  .. .. ..$ max_stat : num [1:36] 0.986 0.271 0.999 0.992 0.997 ...
  .. .. ..$ min_stat : num [1:36] 0.986 0.271 0.999 0.992 0.997 ...
  .. .. ..$ sd_stat  : num [1:36] NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. .. ..$ iqr_stat : num [1:36] 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..$ num_stat : int [1:36] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 4 2 ...
  .. .. ..$ sample   : chr [1:36] "P_5" "P_5" "P_5" "P_5" ...
  .. ..$ : tibble [58 × 12] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. .. ..$ chrom    : chr [1:58] "chr6" "chr6" "chr6" "chr6" ...
  .. .. ..$ pos      : num [1:58] 62251 62311 62340 62422 62455 ...
  .. .. ..$ strand   : chr [1:58] "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
  .. .. ..$ mean_stat: num [1:58] 0.99653 0.8147 0.01016 0.00112 0.01685 ...
  .. .. ..$ med_stat : num [1:58] 0.99653 0.8147 0.01016 0.00112 0.01685 ...
  .. .. ..$ prod_stat: num [1:58] 0.99653 0.8147 0.01016 0.00112 0.01685 ...
  .. .. ..$ max_stat : num [1:58] 0.99653 0.8147 0.01016 0.00112 0.01685 ...
  .. .. ..$ min_stat : num [1:58] 0.99653 0.8147 0.01016 0.00112 0.01685 ...
  .. .. ..$ sd_stat  : num [1:58] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. .. ..$ iqr_stat : num [1:58] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..$ num_stat : int [1:58] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. ..$ sample   : chr [1:58] "P_6" "P_6" "P_6" "P_6" ...
 $ h.chr7: tibble [6 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ sample      : chr [1:6] "P_1" "P_2" "P_3" "P_4" ...
  ..$ methyl_stats:List of 6
  .. ..$ : tibble [42 × 12] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. .. ..$ chrom    : chr [1:42] "chr7" "chr7" "chr7" "chr7" ...
  .. .. ..$ pos      : num [1:42] 10478 10524 10553 10607 10609 ...
  .. .. ..$ strand   : chr [1:42] "+" "+" "+" "+" ...
  .. .. ..$ mean_stat: num [1:42] 1.30e-04 6.08e-05 8.86e-04 3.70e-01 5.11e-01 ...
  .. .. ..$ med_stat : num [1:42] 1.30e-04 6.08e-05 8.86e-04 3.70e-01 5.11e-01 ...
  .. .. ..$ prod_stat: num [1:42] 1.30e-04 6.08e-05 8.86e-04 3.70e-01 5.11e-01 ...
  .. .. ..$ max_stat : num [1:42] 1.30e-04 6.08e-05 8.86e-04 3.70e-01 5.11e-01 ...
  .. .. ..$ min_stat : num [1:42] 1.30e-04 6.08e-05 8.86e-04 3.70e-01 5.11e-01 ...
  .. .. ..$ sd_stat  : num [1:42] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. .. ..$ iqr_stat : num [1:42] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..$ num_stat : int [1:42] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. ..$ sample   : chr [1:42] "P_1" "P_1" "P_1" "P_1" ...
  .. ..$ : tibble [100 × 12] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. .. ..$ chrom    : chr [1:100] "chr7" "chr7" "chr7" "chr7" ...
  .. .. ..$ pos      : num [1:100] 14375 14404 14513 14645 14730 ...
  .. .. ..$ strand   : chr [1:100] "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
  .. .. ..$ mean_stat: num [1:100] 0.99654 0.99818 0.99091 0.88437 0.00069 ...
  .. .. ..$ med_stat : num [1:100] 0.99654 0.99818 0.99091 0.88437 0.00069 ...
  .. .. ..$ prod_stat: num [1:100] 0.99654 0.99818 0.99091 0.88437 0.00069 ...
  .. .. ..$ max_stat : num [1:100] 0.99654 0.99818 0.99091 0.88437 0.00069 ...
  .. .. ..$ min_stat : num [1:100] 0.99654 0.99818 0.99091 0.88437 0.00069 ...
  .. .. ..$ sd_stat  : num [1:100] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. .. ..$ iqr_stat : num [1:100] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..$ num_stat : int [1:100] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. ..$ sample   : chr [1:100] "P_2" "P_2" "P_2" "P_2" ...
  .. ..$ : tibble [65 × 12] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. .. ..$ chrom    : chr [1:65] "chr7" "chr7" "chr7" "chr7" ...
  .. .. ..$ pos      : num [1:65] 10301 10479 10525 10554 10608 ...
  .. .. ..$ strand   : chr [1:65] "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
  .. .. ..$ mean_stat: num [1:65] 0.0001 0.000497 0.003901 0.002497 0.000327 ...
  .. .. ..$ med_stat : num [1:65] 0.0001 0.000497 0.003901 0.002497 0.000327 ...
  .. .. ..$ prod_stat: num [1:65] 0.0001 0.000497 0.003901 0.002497 0.000327 ...
  .. .. ..$ max_stat : num [1:65] 0.0001 0.000497 0.003901 0.002497 0.000327 ...
  .. .. ..$ min_stat : num [1:65] 0.0001 0.000497 0.003901 0.002497 0.000327 ...
  .. .. ..$ sd_stat  : num [1:65] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. .. ..$ iqr_stat : num [1:65] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..$ num_stat : int [1:65] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. ..$ sample   : chr [1:65] "P_3" "P_3" "P_3" "P_3" ...
  .. ..$ : tibble [36 × 12] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. .. ..$ chrom    : chr [1:36] "chr7" "chr7" "chr7" "chr7" ...
  .. .. ..$ pos      : num [1:36] 10300 10478 10524 10553 10607 ...
  .. .. ..$ strand   : chr [1:36] "+" "+" "+" "+" ...
  .. .. ..$ mean_stat: num [1:36] 0.0253 0.5612 0.1343 0.0136 0.0481 ...
  .. .. ..$ med_stat : num [1:36] 0.0253 0.5612 0.1343 0.0136 0.0481 ...
  .. .. ..$ prod_stat: num [1:36] 2.53e-02 1.28e-01 2.89e-03 8.78e-05 1.03e-05 ...
  .. .. ..$ max_stat : num [1:36] 0.0253 0.994 0.2575 0.0235 0.096 ...
  .. .. ..$ min_stat : num [1:36] 0.02527 0.12841 0.011205 0.003735 0.000107 ...
  .. .. ..$ sd_stat  : num [1:36] NA 0.6121 0.1742 0.014 0.0678 ...
  .. .. ..$ iqr_stat : num [1:36] 0 0.4328 0.12314 0.00989 0.04797 ...
  .. .. ..$ num_stat : int [1:36] 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  .. .. ..$ sample   : chr [1:36] "P_4" "P_4" "P_4" "P_4" ...
  .. ..$ : tibble [73 × 12] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. .. ..$ chrom    : chr [1:73] "chr7" "chr7" "chr7" "chr7" ...
  .. .. ..$ pos      : num [1:73] 10478 10524 10553 10607 10609 ...
  .. .. ..$ strand   : chr [1:73] "+" "+" "+" "+" ...
  .. .. ..$ mean_stat: num [1:73] 9.21e-05 1.97e-04 3.80e-03 7.98e-03 2.30e-04 ...
  .. .. ..$ med_stat : num [1:73] 9.21e-05 1.97e-04 3.80e-03 7.98e-03 2.30e-04 ...
  .. .. ..$ prod_stat: num [1:73] 9.21e-05 1.97e-04 3.80e-03 7.98e-03 2.30e-04 ...
  .. .. ..$ max_stat : num [1:73] 9.21e-05 1.97e-04 3.80e-03 7.98e-03 2.30e-04 ...
  .. .. ..$ min_stat : num [1:73] 9.21e-05 1.97e-04 3.80e-03 7.98e-03 2.30e-04 ...
  .. .. ..$ sd_stat  : num [1:73] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. .. ..$ iqr_stat : num [1:73] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..$ num_stat : int [1:73] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. ..$ sample   : chr [1:73] "P_5" "P_5" "P_5" "P_5" ...
  .. ..$ : tibble [59 × 12] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. .. ..$ chrom    : chr [1:59] "chr7" "chr7" "chr7" "chr7" ...
  .. .. ..$ pos      : num [1:59] 10478 10524 10553 10607 10608 ...
  .. .. ..$ strand   : chr [1:59] "+" "+" "+" "+" ...
  .. .. ..$ mean_stat: num [1:59] 0.000766 0.129258 0.001536 0.01666 0.00028 ...
  .. .. ..$ med_stat : num [1:59] 0.000766 0.129258 0.001536 0.01666 0.00028 ...
  .. .. ..$ prod_stat: num [1:59] 0.000766 0.129258 0.001536 0.01666 0.00028 ...
  .. .. ..$ max_stat : num [1:59] 0.000766 0.129258 0.001536 0.01666 0.00028 ...
  .. .. ..$ min_stat : num [1:59] 0.000766 0.129258 0.001536 0.01666 0.00028 ...
  .. .. ..$ sd_stat  : num [1:59] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. .. ..$ iqr_stat : num [1:59] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. .. ..$ num_stat : int [1:59] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. ..$ sample   : chr [1:59] "P_6" "P_6" "P_6" "P_6" ...
>
```

Comment: Try `dplyr::bind_rows(dataTibblesInList)`.

Comment: thank you! & appreciate ur response, but not exactly what i wanted to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `unnest` on the list of tibbles after `select`ing and then rbind the list of datasets with `list_rbind` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
map(dataTibblesInList, ~ .x %>%
   select(methyl_stats) %>%
    unnest(cols = methyl_stats)) %>%
   list_rbind(names_to = "list_name")
```

Comment: Thank you! this is what i needed ```map(dataTibblesInList, ~ .x %>%
   select(methyl_stats) %>%
    unnest(cols = methyl_stats))```